# OpenCV_contrib не собирается в Release

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

Подскажите пожалуйста как разбираться в таких ошибках:

Собрал библиотеку opencv_contrib для VS16 в CMake под виндовс, как на странице продукта описано [на github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib)

прописал пути в настройках проекта.
добавил lib в "Дополнительные зависимости компоновщика":

- opencv_core460d.lib
- opencv_highgui460d.lib
- opencv_imgcodecs460d.lib
- opencv_text460d.lib

минимальный код работает как нужно в режиме Debug:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void main()
{

    Mat image = Mat(800, 1500, CV_8UC4);
    
    imshow("2323", image);
    
    waitKey(0);
}
```

а в Release выдает 2 ошибки:

> ***Ошибка LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1***
>
> ***Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string<char,struct
> std::char_traits,class std::allocator > const &,class
> cv::_InputArray const &)"
> (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@1@@Z).   testest C:\Users\daima\source\repos\testest\Source.obj  1***

я понял что 1я вроди как вытекает со 2й. а по 2й ошибке в описании на сайте милион причин.

в другом проекте ситуация почти наоборот, на релизе все нормально, а если в дебаге компилировать, выдает необработанное исключение. даже не понять где ошибка

Comment: Это не удивительно, ведь собраны дебаг сборки библиотек (с суффиксом d). Собирайте еще и релизный вариант opencv. *выдает необработанное исключение. даже не понять где ошибка* - отладчик надо использовать

Comment: @user7860670 
подскажите пожалуйста, файлы без суффикса d должны генерироваться в CMake или уже потом когда я нажимаю "Open Project" и инсталирую внутри Visual studio? просто их у меня нет.

в конфигурации, когда я в CMake открываю OpenCV у меня только 1 пункт со словом core "BUILD_opencv_core" и он отмечен галочкой

Comment: Все делаю как в гайдах написано:

Качаю с гитхаба opencv обычный и opencv_contrib.

Указываю в CMake обычный opencv конфигурирую.

В EXTRA прописываю путь к модулям из opencv_contrib, опять конфигурирую
нажимаю "Generate" нажимаю "Open Project".

В самой VisualStudio перехожу в режим Release и правой кнопкой Build на ALL_BUILD а потом на INSTALL.

Что на этом этапе можно не так сделать?